# Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, deep-learning, dockerfile, uuid, dbus

I try to install a docker file on servers without Internet so,it just like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-devel-ubuntu18.04
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive  
env http_proxy "http://59.69.106.68:808"
env https_proxy "http://59.69.106.68:808"
env ftp_proxy "http://59.69.106.68:808"
ADD sources.list /etc/apt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git cmake uuid-runtime lsb-release wget software-properties-common && \
    wget --quiet https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz -O ~/go.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf ~/go.tar.gz -C /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/go/bin/go /usr/local/bin/go && \
    rm ~/go.tar.gz
RUN wget --quiet https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh -O ~/llvm.sh && \
    chmod +x ~/llvm.sh && \
    ~/llvm.sh 11 && \
    rm ~/llvm.sh
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/anaconda.sh && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy
RUN conda install -y pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
RUN git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex.git ~/apex && \
    cd ~/apex && \
    bash -c "source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate && python setup.py install && pip install pyelftools" && \
    rm -rf ~/apex
RUN wget --quiet https://github.com/avast/retdec/releases/download/v4.0/retdec-v4.0-ubuntu-64b.tar.xz -O ~/retdec.tar.xz && \
    tar xf ~/retdec.tar.xz -C /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/retdec/bin/retdec-decompiler.py /usr/local/bin/retdec-decompiler && \
    rm ~/retdec.tar.xz
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

And it show many problem like this.

```
Setting up systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.18) ...
Setting up libelf1:amd64 (0.176-1.1build1) ...
Setting up libicu66:amd64 (66.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) ...
Setting up libtinfo6:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up glib-networking-services (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.43ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up cmake-data (3.16.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libstemmer0d:amd64 (0+svn585-2) ...
Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1) ...
Setting up libpackagekit-glib2-18:amd64 (1.1.13-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libbsd0:amd64 (0.10.0-1) ...
Setting up libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up ucf (3.0038+nmu1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1) ...
Setting up libxml2:amd64 (2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.4) ...
Setting up libmagic-mgc (1:5.38-4) ...
Setting up uuid-runtime (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3) ...
Adding group `uuidd' (GID 105) ...
Done.
Warning: The home dir /run/uuidd you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `uuidd' (UID 104) ...
Adding new user `uuidd' (UID 104) with group `uuidd' ...
Not creating home directory `/run/uuidd'.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/uuidd.socket → /lib/systemd/system/uuidd.socket.
Setting up libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.38-4) ...
Setting up librhash0:amd64 (1.3.9-1) ...
Setting up libcbor0.6:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libyaml-0-2:amd64 (0.2.2-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 (1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-data (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) ...
Setting up krb5-locales (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up publicsuffix (20200303.0012-1) ...
Setting up libfido2-1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up wget (1.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libdconf1:amd64 (0.36.0-1) ...
Setting up libcrypt-dev:amd64 (1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) ...
Setting up dmsetup (2:1.02.167-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 (1.1.13-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Setting up libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.6-6ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Setting up xdg-user-dirs (0.17-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libx11-data (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libmpdec2:amd64 (2.4.2-3) ...
Setting up libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 (0.105-26ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libreadline8:amd64 (8.0-4) ...
Setting up libjsoncpp1:amd64 (1.7.4-3.1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20191231-1) ...
Setting up libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up less (551-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 (1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setcap worked! gst-ptp-helper is not suid!
Setting up libarchive13:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-26ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libncursesw6:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up file (1:5.38-4) ...
Setting up libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-2) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.18) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up policykit-1 (0.105-26ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up python3.8 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dbus-user-session (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up openssh-client (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5) ...
Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.8...
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.8...
Setting up dconf-service (0.36.0-1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.14) ...
Setting up python3-idna (2.8-1) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.14) ...
Setting up python3-six (1.14.0-2) ...
Setting up python3-certifi (2019.11.28-1) ...
Setting up python3-pkg-resources (45.2.0-1) ...
Setting up python3-gi (3.36.0-1) ...
Setting up lsb-release (11.1.0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up xauth (1:1.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-chardet (3.0.4-4build1) ...
Setting up python3-urllib3 (1.25.8-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up cmake (3.16.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 (0.36.0-1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.6) ...
Setting up python3-distro-info (0.23ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-apt (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.8) ...
Setting up python3-dbus (1.2.16-1build1) ...
Setting up gsettings-desktop-schemas (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up glib-networking:amd64 (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (2.3ubuntu0.3) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline

Creating config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades with new version

Creating config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades with new version
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/unattended-upgrades.service → /lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service.
Setting up python3-requests (2.22.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.99.9.8) ...
Setting up networkd-dispatcher (2.1-2~ubuntu20.04.3) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/networkd-dispatcher.service → /lib/systemd/system/networkd-dispatcher.service.
Setting up python3-requests-unixsocket (0.2.0-2) ...
Setting up libsoup2.4-1:amd64 (2.70.0-1) ...
Setting up libappstream4:amd64 (0.12.10-2) ...
Setting up packagekit (1.1.13-2ubuntu1.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of force-reload.
Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
Created symlink /etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/pk-debconf-helper.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/user/pk-debconf-helper.socket.
Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.9.8) ...
Setting up packagekit-tools (1.1.13-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.18) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&   apt-get install -y git cmake uuid-runtime lsb-release wget software-properties-common &&    wget --quiet https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz -O ~/go.tar.gz &&    tar xzf ~/go.tar.gz -C /opt/ &&     ln -s /opt/go/bin/go /usr/local/bin/go &&   rm ~/go.tar.gz' returned a non-zero code: 4
```

That really confused me. Could anyone help us？Really thank you.

I had modified the Dockerfile and set the proxy.

Comment: I have the same error btw, but just on my arch linux with pulseaudio

Answer (score 0):

You can start dbus like:

```
apk add dbus
mkdir -p /run/dbus
dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address
```

Or if you get this error locally, it can be caused by Apple Silicon CPUs, in which case choose "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" in the Docker Desktop settings:
[image]